# Can whole declaration be stored as @variable value in Less?

Tags: less

All my **Less variables** are **editable** within a CMS-module and are assigned to the **Less compiler**. It works, if I only use the values like *color*, *font-size*, etc.:

```
body {
    background-color: @bgColor;
}
```

I've created another field for **custom Less**, which I would like to add at the end of my Less file, like:

```
body {
    background-color: @bgColor;
}  
@customLess /* desired OUTPUT: body { color: white; }*/
```

Unfortunately this leads to an `ParseError`.

I'd like to avoid to merge the existing Less and custom Less. I'm not looking for mixins, I guess.

Is it possible to put **whole declarations** in a `@variable`?

Comment: What is the content of `@customLess`?

Comment: @Harry e.g. `body { color: white; }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is very much possible to put whole declarations (including the selector, property + value pair) inside a variable. Those are called as [detached rulesets](http://lesscss.org/features/#detached-rulesets-feature).

While calling them, braces (`()`) must be added. If not, the call will fail and result in compilation error. Below is an extract from the official website.

> Parentheses after a detached ruleset call are mandatory. The call @detached-ruleset; would NOT work.

```css
@customLess: {
  body{
  color: white;
    }
  };
@bgColor: red;
body {
  background-color: @bgColor;
}  
@customLess();
```

Comment: Wow, that was easy. Thanks a lot! :-)